# Fetch a child entity using parent entity in JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have these given below entities and I want to execute some queries and I am not sure how to do it in JPA.

School.java

```
@Data
@Builder
public class School {
    private String schoolName;
    private int schoolId;
    private List<Grade> grades;
}
```

Grade.Java

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Grade {
    private String grade;
    private int gradeId;
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

Student.java

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Student {
    private String studentName;
    private int studentId;
    private List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

Subject.java

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Subject {
    private String subjectName;
    private int subjectId;
}
```

I need to execute these queries:

1. Get all Students By schoolId
2. Get all Students By gradeId
3. Get all Students By schoolId & gradeId

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: If you want to use Spring JPA, did you create the corresponding Repositories for the entities?

Comment: I added this in the Student Repository:  List<Student> findBySchool_SchoolId(Long id);

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, I have created the respective repositories.

Comment: I forgot to add @Entity and Relationship annotations in classes, but please consider that they are in actual code.

Comment: Could you add the repositories and error messages you received when calling the repository methods?

Comment: Please take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference. You can find here how to use spring data named queries

Answer (score 0):

First, please go through the [JPA documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864470/fetch-a-child-entity-using-parent-entity-in-jpa) a bit. Look for `Native Queries`.

For example for first one:

> 1) Get all Students By schoolId

```java
@Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.school_id = :schoolId")
List<Student> findStudentsBySchoolId(@Param("schoolId") Long schoolId);
```

Considering you have following:

- A mapping of `School` in `Student` with mapping column `schoolId`.
- And offcourse a repository for Student in which above method will go. You might also want to extend `JPARepository`.

**Also Note**

> `List<Student> findBySchool_SchoolId(Long id);`

It is not a very good idea to name your methods with underscore in `Java`. [See this](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.3-method-names)